# Access standard props when creating custom components without regurgitating them all in the component file

Tags: react-native, components

When creating custom components with React Native, is it possible to tweak/access the standard props for the objects within that component without having to define them all inside of the component. I know that's a bit vague, so here's the example: I want to have a TouchableOpacity to use throughout my project with many standard style properties, so I will create a component defining those:

```
const ButtonStandard = props => {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} style={styles.Buttons}>
      <Text style={[styles.ButtonText, {color: props.TextColor}]}>
        {props.ButtonText}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

As you can see, the style of the touchable is defined by styles.Buttons, however the style of the text is defined by styles.ButtonText with the ability to change the text color if I need to through props.TextColor (see Edit below). But as the project grows, there may be a situation where I want the text size larger for one button/touchable. So I add "fontSize: props.TextSize" to the text style. And then another scenario pops up where I want to change the padding on the touchable so I add that.

And now we are back to the question: is it possible to avoid redefining every style property for this component (and any other) by some intrinsic method of overwriting the property where needed? Or is the only solution to keep adding props to cover overwriting the style properties as needed? I understand that at some point there's a line where a second or third or fourth component should be created.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: It seems things weren't even working the way I thought they were. I thought I was setting the font color to black and then giving myself the ability to change it with props.TextColor when using the component, but I realized what's actually happening is it completely ignores the styles."style" (in this case ButtonText) for that property, and sets the value to whatever is defined in the component instance OR the default value if the prop is not used in the component instance. I only thought it was working the way I described above because for text, the default value is black which prevented me from realizing it was ignoring the value in styles.ButtonText when I didn't use props.TextColor. My original question does still stand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back when I originally asked this question, I did not really know about or understand the spread operator ("..."). It turns out this is the key to achieving my goal. Some code:

```
style={[
  styles.PrimaryStyles, {
    backgroundColor: props.ButtonColor,
    ...props.SecondaryStyles,
  }
]}
```

This is the style declaration for a custom button. Here, I am setting some PrimaryStyles for the button within the component file. These are things I don't expect to change very often at all such as the shadow or alignContent. Then, I include props.XXX for any properties I more or less want to require. What I mean by more or less is, if you don't specify a value for these props, they will default to their default values (if they can). So in this case, the backgroundColor would end up transparent (for iOS at least). And finally, the use of the spreader which allows us to access all of other props available for that component (in this case I was doing a button).

The way React Native implements these properties is in the order they show up. So if PrimaryStyles sets the backgroundColor to red (for no good reason in this situation), and then props.ButtonColor is green, the button will be green. A more applicable example is if PrimaryStyles sets the width to 20% of the screen width, but I have a button I want to be bigger than the others, I can do the following in the instance of that specific button:

```
<ButtonRectangle>
  ButtonColor={ColorScheme.Orange.e}
    ButtonText={'Roll Again'}
    SecondaryStyles={{
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.5
    }}
    TextSize={20}
    onPress={() => ExerciseGenerator()}
/>
```

I'm sharing this because it's the best way I figured out how to achieve the functionality in the question. But I'm still a very inexperienced programmer and welcome any feedback on this method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches I have come across (there can be many as well), sharing them here,

1. If you take any project, as per best practices in regards to UI/UX, you could use only very few types of buttons based on padding, width, color, disability, shape, and everything. You could consider any famous CSS libraries or react-component libraries they provide only a very specific set of button styles, it's because it is always recommended to have same type of button across the applications. Hence you could create a set of button types and let any parent component choose one.
2. I have also faced an issue, where I had a single text component for the entire project and suddenly new requirements came-up in a such that used text component couldn't handle. This time instead of allowing each property as single prop like instead of `padding`, `margin`, `color` as each one prop, I did expose one prop
   called textStyle where parent component can pass the entire TextStyle and that ll be used to override.

for example,

```js
// from parent component
// pass styles only if required to override existing styles
<Button 
  textStyle={{...anyStyleRelatedToText}} 
  buttonStyle={{ ...anyStyleRelatedToTouchable }}
/>
```

```js
// button component

const ButtonStandard = props => {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={props.onPress} 
      style={[styles.Buttons, props.buttonStyle]}
     >
      <Text style={[styles.ButtonText, props.textStyle]}>
        {props.ButtonText}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```